# When registering a domain, is it possible to designate primary and secondary nameservers by FQDN and IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration

I would like to buy a domain from a registrar and use my own nameservers (assume that they are already hosted,configured and listening on some static IPs in 2 datacenters) for the domain, without designating them by their hosting provider FQDN. Ideally I would like  to designate them by naming them with an FQDN in the new domain. 
After searching a bit I found this:

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System:

> When domain names are registered with a domain name registrar, their
>   installation at the domain registry of a top level domain requires the
>   assignment of a primary name server and at least one secondary name
>   server. The requirement of multiple name servers aims to make the
>   domain still functional even if one name server becomes inaccessible
>   or inoperable.[11] The designation of a primary name server is solely
>   determined by the priority given to the domain name registrar. For
>   this purpose, **generally only the fully qualified domain name of the
>   name server is required, unless the servers are contained in the
>   registered domain, in which case the corresponding IP address is
>   needed as well**.

But the problem is that there is just one text field for each nameserver in the registrar's web interface. I cant supply an FQDN and an IP.

Before trying to contact them I would like to know if I am missing something obvious or asking for something nobody does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to have [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_records#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) in place for your nameservers to avoid the chicken/egg problem.  This is something that your registrar should be able to do.

Comment: I've seen registrars call them everything *but* glue records... So it will involve some searching. Their official name is "glue records" however, and their support personnel should be able to point you in the right direction too, eventually.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can you please tell me if this practice is good/bad/doesnt-matter/common/rare? I am asking because it was difficult to find info about it(until now).

Comment: It's extremely common. It's not included in any basic documentation as end users are extremely unlikely to understand (or care) how the Internet works; likely to screw it up if they try; and likely to misunderstand the concept. Glue records are adequately explained in the RFCs (the only documentation really necessary for the core Internet systems).